# Can Ktor HttpClient JsonFeature use kotlinx.serialization

Tags: kotlin, ktor, kotlinx.serialization

Ktor's HttpClient allows [installing a Json feature](http://ktor.io/clients/http-client/calls/requests.html#specifying-a-body-for-requests).  Does anyone know if this feature can use [kotlinx.serialization library](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) or is it only limited to Gson?  I'm interested in enabling the Json feature for [MPP](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html) projects.

Comment: I think there was a discussion about it on Slack. It's possible, but someone would have to write an implementation. Please give it a go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep. There is `kotlinx.serialization` support in `JsonFeature`

http://ktor.io/clients/http-client/features/json-feature.html#kotlinx-serialization

For the advance multiplatform example of the ktor client with kotlinx.serialization you could look into:
https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlinconf-app